# Routers don't work after PHP project hosted on Digital Ocean (Ubuntu, PHP, Slim, Twig, PuTTY, FileZilla, Apache)

Tags: php, twig, ubuntu-16.04, slim, digital-ocean

I have been trying to host a website (php project) on **Digital Ocean** using **Ubuntu** and apparently it's pretty complicated for the inexperienced.
I uploaded all files to **var/www/html** using FileZilla and the main router doesn't work.
**Instead** of domain/login router the only router that works is **domain/index.php/login**.
I'll show you - http://www.itayperry.com/index.php/login

Why does this happen? The index.php should'nt be there.
I would love for some help :)

BTW, the project is built in a Slim Framework (with Twig) and the main file is index.php containing a routers.php requirement indise of it.

[A FileZilla Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2kXn.png)

Comment: what web server (with version) are you using at local machine and at  Digital Ocean droplet? Do you set webserver config for your site on Digital Ocean?

Comment: I have installed Apache/2.4.18 as my web server in my terminal that's connected to Digital Ocean (when I start the project not on the internet, at localhost home server I just open Xampp of course - that uses Apache 2.4.29). I'm not a big expert in web server config - anything specific you think I should configurate?

Comment: you should check that you properly copied .htaccess file to your DO droplet

Comment: It seems you have complete access to your droplet, right? Then a good approach for you would be to use `git` and `composer` to install a copy of what you developed locally on your server. Usually you do not need to change `.htaccess`, what works on your local machine should just work fine on other machines as well. One benefit of using git here is you don't miss any files accidentally while copying them using an FTP client, specially _hidden_ files like `.htaccess`.

Comment: This is my .htaccess now - and the routers work! I just changed it:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]` 
This was my previous one: 
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule . index.php [L]`
Could really both of them work @Nima?